# extract value from json file

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a file outputted from an API, it contains a JSON.

```
{
    "result": {
        "id": "f34fdasdfaa4364adc42b3a57",
        "modified_on": "2018-06-02T17:08:17.106435Z"
    },
    "success": true
}
```

I need only the value of id (in my case the f34fdasdfaa4364adc42b3a57)

I would do in bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#Pseudocode
id=$(grep -Po '"id":.*?[^\\]",' id.txt)
# /Pseudocode
curl -X DELETE "https://www.example.com/delete/$id"
```

I did look for previous answer and got this: [Parsing JSON with Unix tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools)

But the right answer extract key and value, I would only value (to no manipulate string anymore)

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 10):

```
id=$(jq -r '.result.id' id.txt)
```

Output to variable `id`:

```
f34fdasdfaa4364adc42b3a57
```

Comment: Append to? Thank you in advance

Comment: I misunderstood the question. I've updated my answer.